# How to make a slider mousemove slide

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I would like to make a slider that slide when you hover on its div and increase its speed when you move the mouse to the left or right, decrease when you move to the center. Any Ideas ? Because I made one but it is not smooth at all.

Comment: Whose speed? The slider div's? That made no sense at all to me...

Comment: the Slider's speed and the div wicht wraps the slider

Comment: So the slider is running around the screen, and you're supposed to chase it with the mouse to control its speed...?

Comment: Yes you starts it onmouseover and stop it onmouseleave, and increase its speed by moving the mouse on